# Selector not working in Json formatting [Bug]?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was recently trying out a few things in 1.17 and thought I'd start with displaying an entitys Pos[] with armorstand names. The problem is that I can't get selector argument to work in JSON format anymore, only "name".

```
data merge block -11 31 5 {Text1:'{"score":{"objective":"x_pos","selector":"@p"}}'}
```

That does not work, whilst it used to, but this does

```
data merge block -11 31 5 {Text1:'{"score":{"name":"__Myth_","selector":"@p","objective":"x_pos"}}'}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops! You're mistaking the purpose of `selector`.

`selector` is used *outside* `score` to display the results of a target selector:

```
{"selector":"@p"}
```

If you want to display a `score`, you don't use `selector` inside of it. You instead put the selector *as* the `name` component:

```
{"score":{"name":"@p","objective":"x_pos"}}
```

Comment: Oh right, I reread the wiki and it does kinda state that. Was looking at an example someone wrote online that used selector as its own argument. Well anyways thank you